# Find and add extra key in object of array using lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, lodash

I want to find and add extra key in object of array using **lodash**. I don't want to do in for loop and maintain in temp data.

```
"book": [
  {
    "name": "Hulk",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "mike",
        "id": "100",
      },
      {
        "name": "steve",
        "id": "200"
      }
    ]
  }
],
```

Need to add `detail` object inside `series` array based on `name: mike && id:100` search and return the complete `book` data.

```
{
  "name": "mike",
  "id": "100",
  "detail":{
    "author": 'apple'
    "year": 1956
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this? (note: this modifies the existing object)

```js
const list = [
  {
    "name": "Hulk",
    "series": [
      {
        "name": "mike",
        "id": "100",
      },
      {
        "name": "steve",
        "id": "200"
      }
    ]
  }
];

function addDetail(books, search, detail){
  books.forEach(book => {
    var entry = book.series.find( item => {
      return item.name === search.name && item.id === search.id;
    });
    if(entry){
      entry.detail=detail;
    }
  })
  return books;
}

console.log(addDetail(list, {"name": "mike","id": "100"}, { "author": 'apple', "year": 1956}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You can replace the arrow syntax with the usual function syntax and use lodash for the `forEach` and the `find` to increase compatability with older browser versions.